# How to use two iPhone simulator at the same time?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

How can I use two iPhone simulator at the same time? I need it for doing test as soon as two users uses my app. I need to do a test like if two users are using my app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run two simulators at the same time, but you CAN run a simulator together with other devices. Reference: [Ray Wenderlich cardame tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12735/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-1)

Answer (score 0):

There is not way to do this. Apple would have to build it that way and they didn't.